# Dell PowerVault LTO4-120 Drive displays Error "6" on the drive display

Tags: lto-4, dell-powervault

My newly installed dell PowerVault LTO4-120 Drive (in a PowerEdge T300/Server 2008R2) displays a code "6" and the exclamation indicator is lit up.

What do these mean, and how can I fix them?

Comment: Well that's wonderful for you. But please next time use the "submit a statement" rather than "ask a question" button

Comment: Congratulations.  LTO6 isn't out yet, so maybe you have a top-secret early version.

Comment: Show's a 6 where?  Is it a sticker?

Comment: Dell does not list any PowerVault LTO4 drives as having a display/screen on them. There's a LTO3 drive with an 8 segment display, could it be that one? Since it's a new server, do you still have the build list with part numbers (particularly for the drive)? Also, you're sure it's the LTO drive displaying the number, not a separate device in the top bay (the T300s have a completely separate display in the top bay on the front)?

Comment: Cylndric: who said it's LTO6 ;) , it is an LTO4 drive and the digital display panel on the half height drive on the front of the unit- where the tape goes in is displaying a number 6 with an exclamation mark. does anyone have any idea what this is (internal cable termination to dev/dirty head error ?) - cylindric I'd refrain from posting if you having nothing further of use to add. thanks.

Comment: Chris S: it is this type of device based on an ibm unit a Dell LTO-4 Internal HH SAS Tape Drive - with an integrated display.

Answer (score 7):

You've got a PowerVault LTO4-120:

- The [exclamation point](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/stor-sys/LTO_LC/en/intro.htm#front_panel) means there is a fault.
- The [LCD Code](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/stor-sys/LTO_LC/en/trouble.htm#table_six) "6" means "Tape drive or media error."

The [complete manual is on Dell's website](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/stor-sys/LTO_LC/en/index.htm).

In short, try a different cartridge. If that doesn't work call Dell support. There's a good chance you have a bad tape drive (assuming you've tried multiple tapes and they're all returning that code).